# Why does my boolean inside a for loop get skipped?

Tags: java, for-loop, while-loop

So I am counting votes from an input file, sample.txt:

```
3
Homer REP
Moe IND
Barney DEM
0 1 0 2 2 0
```

My code looks like this:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    int numCans = StdIn.readInt();//Number of candidates
    String[] cans = new String[numCans];//Array containing the candidates
    String[] parts = new String[numCans];//Array that contains the parties.
    int[] votes = new int[numCans];
    int voteCount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < numCans; i++){
        cans[i] = StdIn.readString();
        parts[i] = StdIn.readString();
    }
    while (!StdIn.isEmpty()){//for counting votes
        for(int i = 0; i < votes.length; i++){
            if(StdIn.readInt() == i){
                votes[i]++;
                StdOut.println(i);
            }
        }
        voteCount++;
        }
}
```

So what ends up happening is it counts about 2 votes. Thanks for your help!

Comment: What is the expected output? What is your actual question? Have you tried debugging your code?

Comment: your codes read 3 times in the for loop. so 2 is what you should get though it's not what you expected. your code should call StdIn.readInt() before the for loop (and assigned the returned value to a variable).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`readInt()` will read a new integer from the input *every* time it's called.  So here's what your loop does:

```
        if(StdIn.readInt() == i){
            votes[i]++;
            StdOut.println(i);
        }
```

First, `i` is 0.  The program reads an integer and sees if it's 0.

Suppose the integer isn't 0.  Now your `for` loop loops back, and executes this statement again with `i` = 1.  **Your if statement now reads another integer from the input.**  It doesn't use the same integer it read before.  You told it to read an integer, so it reads one.

I think you can see this isn't what you want to do.  Your `readInt()` must be outside the `for` loop.  I think that once you make this change, you'll see that you don't need the `for` loop at all.

Comment: Thanks so much! I really appreciate the help! I made a modification that made sense to me, having a new variable outside the for loop so that I do not read a new integer each time. For those browsing google, the new code looks like this:
'  while (!StdIn.isEmpty()){//for counting votes
  int vote = StdIn.readInt();
   for(int i = 0; i < votes.length; i++){
    if(vote == i){
     votes[i]++;
     StdOut.println(i);
    }
   }
   voteCount++;
  }'